# Scraping GIF url from Websites

Tags: python, selenium, url, screen-scraping, gif

I am very new to web scraping and trying to scrape gif urls from a website. For example, from gifer.com, search gifs for "smile" and then download urls for all gifs listed.
Below is an example of the source from which I want to extract src element for the video (https://i.gifer.com/ON0.mp4 in this case).

```
<div class="page-media-swipe desktop">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="swipe-left">
      <span class="icon-arrow-left-2  icon" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 44px;"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="media desktop" style="width: 367.462px;">
      <div style="padding-top: 122.462%;">
        <div class="media-container1">
          <div class="media-container2" style="width: 367.462px;">
            <div>
              <video poster="https://i.gifer.com/fetch/w300-preview/d0/d0e6e89a42c43d31b5913e232d87af7b.gif" class="full-media" loop="" autoplay="" playsinline="">
                <source src="https://i.gifer.com/ON0.mp4" type="video/mp4">
              </video>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="swipe-right">
      <span class="icon-arrow-right-2  icon" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 44px;">
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

There are more than thousands of such results and I was advised to use Python and Selenium. However my knowledge of Selenium and Python is limited
I tried below but I am not able to make much headway.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

options = Options()
options.headless = True
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1200")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

driver.get("https://gifer.com/en/gifs/smile")
imgResults = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "media-container2")

print(len(imgResults))
#print(driver.page_source)
for i in range(0,len(imgResults)):
    print(imgResults[i])

driver.quit()
```

Above returns 4 elements-

> <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="fac424650675a90b2a8dee91efdc01f4", element="16e771ca-37d8-45a0-8200-0f03da0b7d14")>
> <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="fac424650675a90b2a8dee91efdc01f4", element="8c9abdcb-bc9d-47da-9958-109e722b3ae9")>
> <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="fac424650675a90b2a8dee91efdc01f4", element="d9640144-4ba1-414b-aa4f-5141387335ef")>
> <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="fac424650675a90b2a8dee91efdc01f4", element="9626db84-1da9-42ad-b314-56222a5e933b")>

Now, how do I grab the source src link for each video element is what I am not getting.

Comment: Do you want to extract gif links or mp4 links? The gif links can be extracted directly from homepage, while to get mp4 links you have to click on each image, i.e. load a new page for each image

Comment: I want to get the mp4 link for all images. There has to be a way to automate this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was wrong, no need to load a new page to get the mp4 link:

```
for img in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "figure a"):
    code = img.get_attribute('href').split('/')[-1]
    link = f'https://i.gifer.com/{code}.mp4'
    print(link)
```

output

```
https://i.gifer.com/fzvh.mp4
https://i.gifer.com/7F5y.mp4
https://i.gifer.com/6qOR.mp4
https://i.gifer.com/3JT.mp4
...
```

You can obtain the list of links in one line

```
links = [f"https://i.gifer.com/{img.get_attribute('href').split('/')[-1]}.mp4" for img in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "figure a")]
```

Comment: I tried to replace imgResults = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "media-container2") from my code with your code but did not work for me. I am unable to figure out where I am going wrong. Being newbie, seems a hard learning curve for me...:(

Comment: @PPandey After `driver.get("https://gifer.com/en/gifs/smile")` add `import time; time.sleep(10)`, try and let me know

Comment: Thanks for coming back to me. I did manage to scrape images using selenium scrollto function along with time.sleep. It is downloading images. I do not know how to put code here. Next stage for me is to extract metadata for the image which I am trying to find a way.

Comment: @PPandey If you post a new question I will try to help